# Asymptotic Bounds for the distribution of $f_n(X_n)$.

Tags: probability, statistics, measure-theory, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $\{X_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of $\mathbb{R}^{k}$-valued random variables defined on some probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ converging almost surely to $X$.

Suppose there is a sequence of functions $\{f_n: \mathbb{R}^{k} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that for every converging sequence $\{h_n\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$, with limit $h$, we have:

$$-\infty<g_1(h) \leq \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(h_n) < \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(h_n) \leq g_2(h)<\infty$$

for some continuous functions $g_1,g_2: \mathbb{R}^{k} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Question: Is there anything clever that we can say about:

$$\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P} \{ \omega \in \Omega \: |\: f_n(X_n(\omega)) \leq c)\} \text{ and } \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P} \{ \omega \in \Omega \: |\: f_n(X_n(\omega)) \leq c)\}, c \in \mathbb{R}$$

What I have in mind is that for a fixed $\omega$, there is $N({\omega},\epsilon)$ such that for $n>N(\omega,\epsilon)$:

$$ f_n(X_n(\omega)) \leq c \implies \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(X_n(\omega)) < c + \epsilon \implies g_1(X(\omega)) \leq c+\epsilon.  $$

If $N(\omega,\epsilon)$ were only a function of $\epsilon$, we could say that for all $\epsilon>0$:

$$ \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \mathbb{P} \{ \omega \in \Omega \: |\: f_n(X_n(\omega)) \leq c)\}\leq \mathbb{P}\{\omega \in \Omega \: | \: g_1(X(\omega))\leq c+\epsilon\}. $$

However, I don't think one can ignore the dependence on $\omega$. If that is the case, I am not sure about how to bound the asymptotic distribution of $f_n(X_n)$. Let me know if this makes sense. Thanks!